# How to optimize table for arbitrary user-made queries?

Tags: mysql, database-design, query-performance

Let's say you have have a large-ish database table, and you'd like to allow users to query it with an API, using several different filter and sort options, and of course supporting pagination.

What would be the best strategy to optimize for such queries? Creating an index for every possible combination of options doesn't seem practical.

For a real-world example of what I have in mind, see this [product search request](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2022-01/objects/Product#query-products) in Shopify. How do large companies handle this kind of queries, with 20 different filters and 10 different sort options, on tables with potentially hundreds of thousands of rows?

In our particular case, we use MySQL in AWS RDS.

Thanks!

Comment: Besides what Bill mentioned in his answer, please note *hundreds of thousands of rows* is typically considered a small amount of data these days. A low end modern laptop could scan that many rows in a table in under a second.

Answer (score 2):

You can't optimize for *everything.*

It's practically the definition of optimization that you are picking *one* type of query that is given some advantage over other queries.

If all queries are "optimized" then none of them has any special advantage. They're just all faster, somehow.

Sounds like you just need a faster computer.

How do large companies do this? A variety of solutions:

- Really honking big computers.
- Caching data in different ways, so the query doesn't need to be run at all in most cases.
- Multiple copies of data, to be indexed in different ways, or denormalized in different ways. The application code therefore needs to know how to match certain queries to the right copy of data.

  Or else start the query against *all* the copies, and whichever one returns quickest becomes the response.

Answer (score 1):

You optimize them like you’d optimize anything else.

Don’t be scared of having several indexes on one table, as long as they are solving a problem then they might be worth having. Think about what queries are allowed and what filters are going to be common and responsible for the majority of the selectivity of your queries. Eg if you had a customer table and you were looking for where the title is 'Mr' and the surname was 'Sayer’, your main selectivity here is going to be driven by the surname - including title in the index is not going to be especially useful. If you know your tables and what they represent then it’s pretty simple to figure out which columns are going to be used to drive your queries.

Remember that the queries will be determined by your application too - you can easily have it so that certain columns must be filtered on.

Ordering by user determined columns is often going to be either the primary key (if it’s some sequence), or a very obvious date column. If you’re indexing columns which might not drive the table selectivity down low enough then adding the order by columns to the end is a sensible tactic

Answer (score 0):

Let's discuss a 2-step process.

Since there is a physical and practical limit on the number of indexes on a table, carefully choose a limited number of 2-column indexes.  Base these on what users typically search on.  For example, Real Estate usually starts with the number of bedrooms and price.

That was the first step; hopefully, it eliminates a large percentage of rows.  The second step is to let the app filter through the rest of the conditions, such as whether there are 2 dishwashers.  These "miscellany" criteria can be thrown into a JSON string.

If your catalog contains both automobiles and dresses, then seriously consider two different tables, each with their own carefully designed indexes, plus JSON.

If you have a billion rows in the table, don't even consider the case where you have to scan all billion rows.  No single server is big fast enough to make that practical.

If you are just starting your design, then *plan for a redesign in a few months*.  Let the first design be a "prototype", wherein you learn what works and what doesn't.  Then *plan* on redoing the schema, *not* just tweaking it.